# Python: Why do some packages get installed as eggs and some as "egg folders"?

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools, egg

I maintain a few Python packages. I have a very similar `setup.py` file for each of them. However, when doing `setup.py install`, one of my packages gets installed as an egg, while the others get installed as "egg folders", i.e. folders with an extension of "egg".

What is the difference between them that causes this different behavior?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[The Internal Structure of Python Eggs, Zip Support Metadata](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/python_eggs.html#zip-safe-and-not-zip-safe) :

> If `zip-safe` exists, it means that the project will work properly when installed as an `.egg` zipfile, and conversely the existence of `not-zip-safe` means the project should not be installed as an `.egg` file [ie. as an `.egg` directory]. The `zip_safe` option to setuptools' `setup()` determines which file will be written. If the option isn't provided, setuptools attempts to make its own assessment of whether the package can work, based on code and content analysis.

Comment: What makes a project zip-safe? Why would you choose one or the other? (I ask as someone packaging a project.)

Comment: From setuptools documentation: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#setting-the-zip-safe-flag

Comment: saffsd's link would be https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#setting-the-zip-safe-flag now

Comment: 10 years later, @saffsd's link now would be https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/zip_safe.html (including "this flag is considered obsolete")

Answer (score 5):

A single egg file is in fact a zip archive with a particular directory structure inside. Per the [zipimport](http://docs.python.org/library/zipimport.html) documentation, only `.py`, `.pyc`, and `.pyo` files can be imported from zip files. So, if the package needs to import other kinds of module resources (like compiled c code; `.so` files, `.pyd` files) it won't work as a zip file.

I don't know if this is the *only* reason that some eggs won't work as zip archives, but I think it is the main reason.

Comment: It's not the main reason.  It's not even a *correct* reason.  setuptools adds special loaders to make .so and .pyd files work even with a compressed egg.  The other answer is the correct one.